# Mysqli Database PHP list slow updating

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have this PHP code connected up to a database and echo out a list of email adresses. The problem is that it's updating extremly slowly even if I'm refreshing the page. My first thought was that the browser cached the information and kept it there for a while but I added this: `

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />`
```

In my head tag to stop the browser from caching but it didn't work and the list is still extremely slow. Any help is appreciated. (Sorry for some of the varibles being in swedish).

```
                    <?php 
                    $servername = "***********";
                    $username = "***********";
                    $password = "***********";
                    $dbname = "***********";

                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }

                    $sql = "SELECT mejl FROM mejllista";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<li>" . $row["mejl"] . "</li>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 resultat";
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                ?>
```

Comment: Try using Prepared Statements, which will take care of the caching itself.

Comment: how many entrys has the table `mejllista`?

Comment: How many records (emails) have you got ?

Answer (score 0):

So, PHP will store output generated in a loop (with an echo for instance) to an output buffer. Once the buffer is full it will flush it to the output - your webpage.

To override this, you can implicitly call flush and ob_flush:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

```
<?php 
    $servername = "***********";
    $username = "***********";
    $password = "***********";
    $dbname = "***********";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT mejl FROM mejllista";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "<li>" . $row["mejl"] . "</li>";

              //Flush the system write buffers
              flush();
              //Send the contents of the output buffer  
              ob_flush();
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 resultat";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

On each iteration of the while loop flush the write buffer and send the contents of the buffer to the page.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works instantly now :) I would vote you up but I'm not high enought rank. Anyway thank you! :D